# is ajenti a cpanel/virtualmin replacement?

Tags: virtual-machine, webserver, cpanel

i am looking for a website account management on a server;

i own and manage an almost classic "reseller" shared host VPS; i host several "Accounts", each account has 1 subdirectory, own domains (virtual-host) and database; each account has 1 or more or more websites: static-html, wordpress, django, & drupals

The only difference is that i'm my own clients; i'm the only one with admin access to the machine, and i'm installing the websites;

i DO require as much separation and isolation as possible, both for security and for manageability;

So far i used virtualmin (a webmin plugin) which handles "servers", i.e. it manages hosting accounts.  VirtualMin took care to assign users to  a "server", set individual permissions per "Server" files, handle individual "Server" backup etc.

today i saw a reference to "Ajenti" in wikipedia, and tested it,

i installed ajenti-V

but i don't see the concept of "account"; only individual "websites".

it means i don't have isolated accounts, users-per-account, emails-per-account etc.

does Ajenti support an "Account" notion, or is it only for individual entities (i.e. i need to make sure user A is permitted and assigned to "account" A?

Answer (score 3):

You can create multiple user accounts in `Configure > Users` section, and then each user can have their own websites and mailboxes.

I'm the main developer of Ajenti and Ajenti V, so just let me know if you need more help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ajenti with [Ajenti-V](http://ajenti.org/#product-ajenti-v) (web hosting plugin), and I can say that it's easily a replacement. I'm happy with it so far.